# Como carregar página php utilizando javascript (com método GET)?

Tags: php, javascript, get

Boa tarde!

Estou com o seguinte problema: Possuo uma página php (produtos.php), onde o corpo da página pode variar de acordo com 2 arquivos (produtos-filtros.php e produtos-wfiltros.php) que são carregados via javascript utilizando load. Os dois arquivos em questão dependem do método GET para funcionarem, no entanto, por serem carregados via javascript não encontram a variável passada via url (Enquanto que a página produtos.php encontra o get normalmente).

Desde já, grato pela ajuda!

```html
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['categoria'])){
    $cat = $_GET['categoria'];
}

?>
<!-- CABEÇALHO -->

<?php require_once 'includes/header.php';?>

<!-- FIM CABEÇALHO -->

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:90px">
 
  <label class="switch" style="float:right;">
  <input type="checkbox" id="testeste" onchange="getval(this);" checked >
  <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>

</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>

 $(document).ready( function(){
 $('#produtos').load('includes/produtos/produtos-filtros.php');
 refresh();
 });

 function getval(sel){ 
 if ($('#testeste').is(':checked')){   
 $('#produtos').load('includes/produtos/produtos-filtros.php');
 } else { 
 $('#produtos').load('includes/produtos/produtos-wfiltros.php');}
 }
</script>




<div id="content " style="margin-top:130px;">
     <div class="container" id="produtos">

     </div>
</div>



<script  src="componentes/js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>





PÁGINA PRODUTOS-FILTROS (Exemplo):

<?php 

if(isset($_GET['categoria'])){
    $cat = $_GET['categoria'];
}


/*EFETUAR BUSCA POR PRODUTOS DENTRO DESSA CATEGORIA NO BD*/

print_r("

<div class=\"col-md-4 col-sm-6 borda-product\" onclick=\"location.href = 'produto-detalhes.php';\">
 <div class=\"product\">
  <div class=\"product_image\" >
     <img  src=\"imagens/img-produtos/$pro_nome.jpg\" alt=\"First slide\">    
  </div>
  <div class=\"product_info\">
      <h6 class=\"product_name\"><a href=\"produto-detalhes.php\">$pro_nome</a></h6>
      <div class=\"product_price\">$pro_preco</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

    ");


?>
```

Comment: Pra que você quer o get? Serviria guardar o seu valor numa variável js?
 mostre o código das duas outras páginas

Comment: Boa tarde, Guilherme!
A variável passada via GET servirá para selecionar a categoria ou gênero do produto no banco. As outras páginas ainda não estão completas, pois falta conseguir passar a variável para elas. 
Vou adicionar um exemplo básico de como as outras páginas trabalham.
Grato pela resposta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa passar a variavel do php $categoria para javascript e depois os parâmetros pelo load().

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var cat = <?php echo $cat; ?>

$("#produtos").load("includes/produtos/produtos-filtros.php", {categoria:cat})
</script>
```

Comment: Bom dia, Juliano! 

Funcionou perfeitamente! Grato, pois no quesito javascript ainda não estou avançado como no php. 
O único adendo que coloco é que o Método load() do javascript usa o request do tipo GET caso o parâmetro não seja passado, como nesse caso passamos o parâmetro, no php deve-se usar o $_REQUEST ao invés do $_GET.
Mais uma vez, obrigado pela resposta!